# go back to menu select if files are the same age

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to make a bash script where the user picks a number from 1-5 with 5 being to exit the menu. For option 3 I want to check if 2 files exist and if they do check what one is older and if they are the same age I want to display that they are the same age but when I run the script if the one or both of the files don't exist then it still displays files are the same age. Not sure how to fix this. any help is appreciated.

```
   #!/bin/bash

# usage: ./menu_script

exitvar=false 

while [ $exitvar = "false" ]  # keep looping until exit equals true
  do

echo -n "Please enter one of the following options:
    1. Move empty files
    2. Check file size
    3. which file is newer
    4. file check rwx
    5. exit
    Enter choice:  "
read number

case $number in
1) echo "Move empty files"
/home/student/move_empty
if [ $? -eq 55 ]
then
echo "move empty:FAILURE"
fi
;;

2) echo "Check file size"
echo -n "Enter a file name to check: "
read -r sourcefile

/home/student/file_size "$sourcefile"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "file_size:success"

fi

if [ $? -eq 2 ]
then
echo "file_size:failure"
fi 
;;

3) echo "Which file is newer"
echo -n "Enter first file to check: "
read  file1

if [ -f $file1 ]  # check if the file exists?
 then
   echo $file "exists!"
else
echo $file "does not exist"
  fi

echo -n "Enter secound file to check: "
read  file2

if [ -f $file2 ]  # check if the file exists?
 then
   echo $file2 "exists!"
else
echo $file "does not exist"
  fi  

if [[ $file1  -ot $file2 ]]; 
  then
  echo $file1  is newer than $file2

elif [[ $file2  -ot $file1 ]]; 
  then
  echo $file2  is newer than $file1
else
 echo files are the same age
fi
;;

4) echo "File check rwx"
echo -n "Enter a file name to check: "
read  sourcefile

if [ -e $sourcefile ]  # does the source file exist? 
 then
   echo $sourcefile "exists!"
else
echo $sourcefile "does not exist"
  fi     

#check for write permission
if [ -w $sourcefile ]
then
echo $sourcefile "is writable"
fi

#check for execute permission
if [ -x $sourcefile ]
then
echo $sourcefile "is executable"
fi

#check for read premission
if [ -r $sourcefile ]
then
echo $sourcefile "is readable"

fi
;;

5) echo "exit"
   exitvar="true"
   ;;
 *) echo "Invalid option try again"
   ;;
 esac
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the number 3 section which should fix your issue.

```
3) echo "Which file is newer"
  echo -n "Enter first file to check: "
  read  file1
  [ -n "$file1" ] ||  { echo "You have not given any filename" >&2; exit 1; }
  if [ -e $file1 ]; then  # check if the file exists?
    echo "$file1" "exists!"
  else
    echo  "$file1" "does not exist"
    exit 1
  fi

  echo -n "Enter secound file to check: "
  read  file2
  [ -n "$file2" ] ||  { echo "You have not given any filename" >&2; exit 1; }
  if [ -e "$file2" ]; then  # check if the file exists?
    echo "$file2" "exists!"
  else
    echo "$file2" "does not exist"
    exit 1
  fi

  if [[ $file1 -nt $file2 ]]; then
    echo "$file1  is newer than $file2"
  elif [[ $file2 -nt $file1 ]]; then
    echo "$file2  is newer than $file1"
  else
    echo "$file1 and $file2 are the same age"
  fi
;;
```

- You should be using `[[ ]]` if you're writing a bash script, (which seems you are)

Answer (score 0):

If file(s) doesn't exist, you are still doing operation on them that's why the issue.

Try to `continue` if a file doesn't exist. `continue` will take the control to start of while loop.

```
    if [ -f $file1 ]  # check if the file exists?
     then
       echo $file "exists!"
     else
        echo $file "does not exist"
        continue
     fi
```